# Pandas Merge Causing Data to go to Wrong Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes:

df1:

```
        ID CODE   CD1   CD2
0      11526.0   1A    NWZ
1      11527.0   1C    NWZ
```

df2

```
        CD_Code   CID_CODE   OC_NME    OC_CDE
0         Mal3     11529     6A        Main Area
1         Mal2     11526     6B        Side Area
```

I am trying to merge these data frames on `df1['ID CODE']` and `df2['CID_CODE']`. I want to append df1 onto df2 and input the values if there is a match. If there is no match, NaN is fine.

So, with that logic in mind, I have written a merge:

```
df1_plus_df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how="left", left_on=['CID_CODE'], right_on=['ID CODE'])
```

Now, the resulting merge is *almost* exactly what I need.

I'm getting the values, but they're overwriting existing columns.
df1_plus_df2:

```
        CD_Code   CID_CODE   OC_NME    OC_CDE      ID CODE   CD1   CD2
0         Mal3     11529     6A        Main Area   NaN       NaN   NaN
1         Mal2     11526     11526.0   1A          NaN       NaN   NaN
```

If you see in `df1_plus_df2[1]`, the values have overwritten the values in the previous 2 columns. I also did not get the third column from df1 to carry over.

Overall, the weird thing here is I cannot understand why the columns get appended, but then the values overwrite existing df2 values.

Here's the output I *NEED*, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to not get it:
df1_plus_df2:

```
        CD_Code   CID_CODE   OC_NME    OC_CDE      ID CODE   CD1   CD2
0         Mal3     11529     6A        Main Area   NaN       NaN   NaN
1         Mal2     11526     6B        Side Area   11526.0   1A    NWZ
```

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the column you want to merge on? `CID_CODE` and `ID CODE` have all the same value 11526. If you try to append these two dataframes it won´t be able to know how to merge them since there is no condition expecified.

Please explain more clearly what is what you want to merge.

EDIT.

I run your code and that is what I see.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID CODE": [11526.0, 11527.0], "CD1" : ["1A", "1C"], "CD2": ["NWZ", "NWZ"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"CD_Code": ["Mal3", "Mal2"], "CID_CODE": [11529, 11526], "OC_NME": ["6A", "6B"], "OC_CDE": ["Main Area", "Side Area"]})

df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on=['CID_CODE'], right_on=['ID CODE'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
    CD_Code CID_CODE    OC_NME      OC_CDE      ID CODE   CD1   CD2
0   Mal3    11529       6A          Main Area   NaN       NaN   NaN
1   Mal2    11526       6B          Side Area   11526.0   1A    NWZ
```

Are you doing something else before the merge? What pandas version are you using?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post for a bit of clarity on the values. That was my mistake, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I am merging the frames based on the values in `CID_CODE`. I want to see if their values exist in `ID CODE`, and if they do append them to the data frame. I'm not sure what condition you mean beyond that

Comment: It is very extrange. When I run your code it works. See my edits

Comment: So the only other thing is these values are coming in the form of Excel sheets, I am importing the sheets into dataframes. They're large files, df1 is ~650 rows and df2 is ~6000 rows. When I try and do the merge I'm getting an error "cannot merge object and float64 columns". I was doing a cast to string which then led me to the result, which I have posted in the question and I am stuck. Pandas version 0.25.2

Comment: I see. Your problem is that 11526.0 == 11526 is True if both are number types, but when you transform both to strings they are not the same because it checks "11526.0" == "11526", it would be like comparing "hello" == "hello.0" which is False.

Comment: That makes sense. I was able to solve my issue by first casting `ID CODE` to INT then STR to kill the trailing 0. This then worked perfectly. Your comments and guidance led me to this, so I will accept this as the answer. Thanks for your help :)